# How to query an XML column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xml-parsing

Recently an Oracle database I used was migrated to PostgreSQL 12.8. But i can't seem to understand how to query the XML field in postgresql.

XML Field:

```
<abap version="1.0">
    <values>
        <ARCHIVE_INDEX>
            <FUNCTION>DARA</FUNCTION>
            <MANDANT>400</MANDANT>
            <DEL_DATE>0000-00-00</DEL_DATE>
            <SAP_OBJECT>PRINTDOC</SAP_OBJECT>
            <AR_OBJECT>ISU_BILL</AR_OBJECT>
            <OBJECT_ID>600030023597</OBJECT_ID>
            <RESERVE>COMMIT</RESERVE>
        </ARCHIVE_INDEX>
    </values>
</abap>
```

**On Oracle:**
*Query:*
`SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(b.XML, '//ARCHIVE_INDEX/OBJECT_ID') AS OBJECT_ID FROM table_name b`
*Results:*
OBJECT_ID
600030023597

**On PostgreSQL:**
*Query:*
`SELECT xpath('//ARCHIVE_INDEX/OBJECT_ID', b.XML::xml) AS OBJECT_ID FROM table_name b`
*Results:*
OBJECT_ID
{[XML]}

I'm trying to get the result to match what it previously was on oracle.

Comment: Use:  `SELECT (xpath('//ARCHIVE_INDEX/OBJECT_ID/text()', b.XML::xml))[1] AS OBJECT_ID FROM table_name b`  The `text()` function gets the node texts that match the xpath query.  The extra parens and `[1]` gets the first element.  The Oracle behavior, while convenient, is not strictly correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost answered in comments, but for sake of completeness here an example:

Having

```
create table public.sample1 (
    id int4 not null,
    xml_content xml null
);

insert into sample1 values (1, 
'<abap version="1.0">
    <values>
        <ARCHIVE_INDEX>
            <FUNCTION>DARA</FUNCTION>
            <MANDANT>400</MANDANT>
            <DEL_DATE>0000-00-00</DEL_DATE>
            <SAP_OBJECT>PRINTDOC</SAP_OBJECT>
            <AR_OBJECT>ISU_BILL</AR_OBJECT>
            <OBJECT_ID>600030023597</OBJECT_ID>
            <RESERVE>COMMIT</RESERVE>
        </ARCHIVE_INDEX>
    </values>
</abap>
');
```

Then

```
select (xpath('//ARCHIVE_INDEX/OBJECT_ID/text()'
, xml_content))[1]::text::bigint object_id from sample1;
```

Where the return value of xpath function is an xml array 1 based, after that a pair of type casts.

[Working sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/70b24/2) and [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html)